# Why am I getting NoMethodError Iterating on Hash Embedded in Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parameters, hashmap, nomethoderror, aor-embedded-array

I keep receiving the following error message for my code. (Trying to iterate through a hash embedded in an array to return the highest value and its associated key). **The error comes after the first loop.**

> Traceback (most recent call last):    6: from main.rb:53:in `<main>'  5:
>   from main.rb:53:in`map'  4: from main.rb:53:in `each'    3: from
>   main.rb:53:in`times'     2: from main.rb:58:in `block in <main>'     1:
>   from main.rb:58:in`each' main.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>':
>   undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
#assigns number of participants in array 
num_participants = 2 

#embedded hash within array (of participants)

participants = [{"participant_name"=> "Liz Lee", "cupcakes_sold" => 41, "cupcakes_left" => 31, "cakes_sold" => 12, "cakes_left" => 2}, 
{"participant_name" => "John Jay", "cupcakes_sold" => 44, "cupcakes_left" => 2, "cakes_sold" => 22, "cakes_left" => 4}] 

#calculates total amount raised by each hash in participants array
#and populates new hash key 'proceeds' for each hash in participants array
#then loops through to update most_raised amount and assign highest_earner

counter = 0
most_raised = 0
highest_earner = ""

num_participants.times.map do 

 profits =  2 * participants[0 + counter]['cookies_sold']  - 
 participants[0 + counter]['cookies_left'] - 
 participants[0 + counter]['cookies_sold'] + 
 6 * participants[0 + counter]['cakes_sold'] - 
 3 * participants[0 + counter]['cakes_sold'] - 
 3 * participants[0 + counter]['cakes_left']
 participants[0 + counter]['proceeds'] = profits.to_i
 puts "\nProceeds raised by #{participants[0+counter]['participant_name'].capitalize}: 
 $#{participants[0+counter]['proceeds']}" +"."
 counter+=1

 ['participant_name', 'proceeds'].each do 

  if (max < profits)
   most_raised = participants[0+counter]['proceeds'].to_i
   highest_earner = participants[0+counter]['participant_name']
  end
 end
end

puts "#{highest_earner.capitalize} raised the most:$#{most_raised}"
```

Comment: What's `participants`, didn't you forget assigning the block variable?

Comment: participants is my array of hashes

Comment: don't see it anywhere

Comment: Provided that `participants` does indeed exist, the error likely means that `0+counter` goes outside of its bounds.

Comment: Where do you set `num_participants`?

Comment: I set it in earlier code, set by user input.

Comment: I think the problem is that i need to set parameters to iterate through the embedded hashes, not just the array of hashes, ie num_participants.times.map do participant.each do... but I'm not sure of he syntax for this... (participant is each hash... in pseudo-code)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set counter=0 you never get past the first hash when you do participants[0 + counter] (which always equals participants[0] )

I missed your counter+=1
Sorry this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: so, the loop worked for updating my position in the array (bc the first loop was working and it populated the 'proceeds' key).. the problem was something within the syntax of the second loop

Comment: i did separated loops though, and somehow that worked

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I separated my loops.

```
#calculates total amount raised by each participant
counter = 0
participants.each do 
  profits =  2 * participants[0 + counter]['cookies_sold']  - 
             participants[0 + counter]['cookies_left'] - participants[0 + counter]['cookies_sold'] + 6 * participants[0 + counter]['cakes_sold'] - 
             3 * participants[0 + counter]['cakes_sold'] - 3 * 
             participants[0 + counter]['cakes_left']
  participants[0 + counter]['proceeds'] = profits.to_i
  puts "\n\e[36mProceeds raised by #{participants[0+counter]['participant_name'].capitalize}:\e[0m $#{participants[0+counter]['proceeds']}" +"."
  counter+=1
end

#calculates highest earner and highest amount raised
counter = 0
most_raised = 0 
highest_earner = ""
participants.each do 
  if (most_raised < participants[0+counter]['proceeds'])
    most_raised = participants[0+counter]['proceeds'].to_i
    highest_earner = participants[0+counter]['participant_name']
    counter+=1
  end
end
puts most_raised 
puts highest_earner
```